# Verben mit den meisten Vokalwechseln

Tags: verb, conjugation, curiosity, vowel

Es gibt viele Verben mit sechs Vokalwechseln. Da ich kein Sprachforscher bin, verwende ich den Begriff *Vokalwechsel* wahrscheinlich falsch – ich meine damit:

```
  helfen [Infinitiv]
  half   [Präteritum]
  hilft  [Präsens]
geholfen [Partizip II]
  hälfe  [Konjunktiv II, immer häufiger verwendet]
  hülfe  [Konjunktiv II, veraltete Form]
  =======
  [a, e, i, o, ä, ü] = 6 Vokale
```

Ich habe darüber nachgedacht, aber mir fällt einfach kein Verb, das mehr als sechs Vokalwechsel hat, ein. Gibt es welche?

Comment: Hilfreiches Stichwort: [Ablautreihen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ablaut#Ablaute_bei_den_deutschen_Verben). (Der verlinkte Wikipedia-Artikel ist sicher nicht die beste Ressource zum Thema.)

Comment: Das Verb [**stehlen**](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/stehlen) kann zumindest mithalten. Laut Duden hat es, wie _helfen_, zwei verschiedene Konjunktiv-II-Formen und kommt dadurch auf die 6 Vokale [a, e, ie, o, ä, ö]. --- Aber wie ist der erste Satz der Frage gemeint?

Comment: Du brauchst mehr Tempora, um die Möglichkeit zu betrachten, dass ein 7-facher Vokalenwechsel stattfindet. Mir fällt noch nicht ein, was das andere Tempus sein könnte.

Comment: Da eine Form der Ausgangspunkt ist hat man bei 6 Varianten nur 5 Wechsel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ich wage zu behaupten, dass 6 das Maximum ist.

Erstmal muss man bedenken, dass das theoretische Maximum bei 8 liegt. Also 5 Vokale und 3 Umlaute. Sehr viel Steigerungspotenzial ist da nicht mehr gegeben.

Es gibt recht regelmäßige Muster, die sich immer wieder wiederholen. 6 Vokale, wie in deinem Beispiel, ist mitnichten eine Seltenheit.

Um die 6 zu erreichen, musst du erstmal ein Wort mit Umlaut haben. Die Suche kannst du [hier](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-V/Listen/Umlaut-Irreg-Pres.html?MenuId=Word21137) starten. Alternativ auch ein Wort mit Ablaut, in der Hoffnung, dass es einen Umlaut zum Ablaut gibt. Einige Wörter [hier](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-V/Texte/Ablaut.html?MenuId=Word21138).

Du kannst dir aus jeder der Kategorien ein beliebiges Wort picken und überprüfen, ob das Wort die 6 Vokale knackt. Tut es das nicht, gilt das auch für alle anderen der Gruppe.

Na gut, das stimmt beinah. Es gibt ja einige Wörter mit zwei Konjunktivformen. Also, wenn du ein Muster findest, wo 6 Vokale erreicht werden ohne die zweite Konjunktivform, so brauchst du dann nur das eine Wort in der Gruppe finden, welches doch eine solche Form hat. Und tadaaaa, da ist das Wort.

Haken ist, denke ich, dass du immer nur auf 5 Vokale kommst und nur die Wörter mit zwei Konjunktivformen die 6 erreichen.

Grundsätzlich muss für dein Wort folgendes stimmen:

1. Der Vokal des Imperativs unterscheidet sich vom Infinitiv. (2 Vokale)
2. Der Vokal der zweiten Person Singular Präsens unterscheidet sich vom Infinitiv und Imperativ. (3 Vokale)
3. Der Vokal der ersten Person Singular Präteritum unterscheidet sich vom Infinitiv, Imperativ und zweiter Person Singular Präsens. (4 Vokale)
4. Der Vokal des Partizips II unterscheidet sich vom Infinitiv, Imperativ, zweiter Person Singular Präsens und erster Person Singular Präteritum. (5 Vokale)
5. Der Vokal des Konjunktivs II unterscheidet sich vom Infinitiv, Imperativ, zweiter Person Singular Präsens, erster Person Singular Präteritum und Partizip II. (6 Vokale)
6. Es gibt einen zweiten Konjunktiv II, der sich... — Na, du weißt schon was. (7 Vokale)

In einer stichartigen Probe habe ich jedoch kein Wort gefunden, dass alle sechs Bedingungen erfüllt.

Comment: Der jeweils zweite Buchstabe in S*y*stem und T*y*p ist ebenfalls ein Vokal. Damit kommt man mit a, e, i, o, u, ä, ö, ü und y schon auf 9 Vokale. Zählt man die Diphthonge au, eu, äu, ai, ei und die verdoppelten bzw. langen Vokale aa, ee, ie, oo und uu auch noch extra, ist man bei 19 verschiedenen Vokalen. Orientiert man sich aber nicht am geschriebenen, sondern am gesprochenen Deutsch, sind es sogar noch mehr. Deutsch ist, verglichen mit anderen Sprachen, besonders reich an Vokalen. Wikipedia listet 23 verschiedene gesprochene deutsche Monophthonge auf. Dazu kommen noch zahlreiche Diphthonge.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ich hatte es befürchtet und kurz überlegt, ob ich dazu was schreibe. Beispielsweise "ie" kommt durch aus vor, aber immer dann, wenn "ie" auftritt, gibt es kein einfaches "i". Damit macht es keinen Sinn, diesen separat aufzuzählen, weil die beiden sich gegenseitig exklusiv ausschließen. Wirfst du einen Blick auf Wörter mit "ei", um sich mal ein Diphthong anzuschauen, wirst du feststellen, dass die "erweiterte Vokalliste" dich auch kein Stück weiter bringt. "Laufen", bswp. hat "au", "äu" und "ie" und das ist sozusagen das Gegenstück zu "a", "ä" und "i". Boring.

Answer (score 2):

Inf. - werfen;
Prät. - warf;
Part. - geworfen;
Imp. - Wirf!;
Subst. - der Wurf;
Konj. - würfe;

Damit sind wir auch bei 6.

Bezieht man das Substantiv und dessen Pluralform ein, erhält man:

bergen, barg, geborgen, birg, Burg, bärge, bürge (7 Ablaute)

sprechen, sprach, gesprochen, sprich, Spruch, Sprüche, spräche (auch 7)

Ich denke daß mehr als 7 Ablaute nicht möglich sind, da meiner Ansicht nach kein Wort alle 3 Umlaute verwendet.